# CMake, VS2012 and Boost 1.54.0: libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib missing

Tags: visual-c++, boost, cmake

I built boost 1.54.0 with Visual Studio 2012 x64.

I tried to build a small demo that is using boost filesystem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Usage: tut1 path\n";
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << argv[1] << " " << file_size(argv[1]) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

CMake is used to setup the corresponding project for VS2012 x64:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.9)
PROJECT(FilesystemTest)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/)
# Visual Studio 2010 Pro Standard: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /Zm1000 /EHsc /GR
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /Zi /EHsc /GR- /MP /openmp") 

SET(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX  "d")

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)

# Unicode rules!
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_UNICODE)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

LINK_DIRECTORIES(   ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

file(GLOB FilesystemTest_SOURCES src/*.*)

# Create a target for the library
ADD_EXECUTABLE(FilesystemTest
    ${FilesystemTest_SOURCES})
```

But when compiling I get 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib' is missing.

Perviously I used boost 1.53.0 - everything was working perfect when using boost 1.53.0.

When looking into the boost 1.54 lib folder there is only a 'boost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib' and a 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-sgd-1_54.lib'

I compiled boost using this instructions:

1. Download boost 1.54.0 from http://www.boost.org/
2. Extract files (e.g. “C:\thirdparty\vs2013\x64\boost_1_54_0”)
3. Start Visual Studio 2012 x64 command prompt
4. Change to boost directory (e.g. “cd C:\thirdparty\vs2010\x64\boost_1_54_0”)
5. Execute .\bootstrap.bat
6. Execute b2 address-model=64 toolset=msvc-11.0 --build-type=complete stage

If only certain libraries (for instance filesystem) are need step 6 can be replaced by this:

```
b2 address-model=64 toolset=msvc-11.0 --build-type=complete stage --with-filesystem --with-signals --with-system
```

I could not figure out what is working wrong. Any ideas?

**Update**
Yesterday I tried again: I used the same commands and I finally got a 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib' file. No idea why it is working now. I installed a few VS2012 updates and also removed my VS2013 Preview installation. But I have no clue why it is working now.

Comment: @drescherjm I changed the boost build instructions accordingly

Comment: Other than the comment I made hours ago and deleted since you updated the build instructions I seem to be building the pretty much same way for boost 1.53.0 (I have not moved to 1.54 yet): "x:/Other/Libraries/boost_1_53_0/bjam.exe -j%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% --without-python --without-mpi address-model=64 --build-dir=x:/x64.2/VC.110/Libraries/Boost-1.53.0/build --prefix=x:/x64.2/VC.110/Libraries/Boost-1.53.0 --toolset=msvc-11.0 --build-type=complete stage install"

Comment: I think I could solve this by defining either ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK) or SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) before the find_package(boosr) call.

Comment: If this is not a question any longer... perhaps you could answer your own question, so this does not show up at the top of the "unanswered CMake questions" list. It appears to be more of a "why didn't boost build the right libraries" question than a CMake question. If you don't feel answering your own question is warranted, perhaps remove the CMake tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday I tried again: I used the same commands and I finally got a 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib' file. No idea why it is working now. I installed a few VS2012 updates and also removed my VS2013 Preview installation. But I have no clue why it is working now.